# How to find out was the scrolling performed manually or triggered by method?

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

My front-end is constructed in Angular 7 by the way.
The question is - is there (in 2019 =)) any real way to find out who (or what) was the 'trigger' of scrolling?

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
  onAnyScrollEvent(event) {
    /* we are getting here if ANY event occurs */
  }
```

I mean, you can scroll using mouse or you can write a function that will scroll for you.
Something like (just using *el* from ElementRef):

```
this.el.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

So... any valuable tips will be greatly appreciated : )

*UPDT*.
For a example I have some auto-scrolling stuff (logs) in my component.
 But sometimes I need to read (check out) some info without it and I have to stop auto-scrolling process when I scroll the mouse by myself. So how can I tell my code that this current scrolling is mine? That's the problem. Well, I avoided it using some other logic, but the curious question remains.

Comment: _The question is - is there (in 2019 =)) any real way to find out who (or what) was the 'trigger' of scrolling?_ Nope - not definitively.

Comment: @RandyCasburn this is awful if it's true :(

Comment: Why, what makes it awful? Described a detailed use case for needing to know, not. that an element was scrolled, not how far it scrolled, or how fast or in what direction...but what mechanism initiated it. Because a finger is different than a mouse is different than a voice and is different than a function call. Then, describe why you need it to TC39. Simple.

Comment: What I think is awful is a question without a purpose other than exploring the world of  "what if" without a real problem to solve.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated my question to show you the reason. And btw why are u so angry to me? : ) That's normal to have a desire to get smarter watever it takes.

Comment: I'm not at all angry at anyone. I find it silly to ask questions that have no purpose other than to a question "but why, I wanna!" (in 2019 =) fashion)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Well, thanks anyway

Comment: _I have some auto-scrolling stuff_ - "auto" indicating "started programmatically. _when I scroll the mouse_ - mouseEvent, started by user interaction. **_So how can I tell my code that this current scrolling is mine?_** - That is exactly what eventListeners are for - "listen for the mouse event, then tell the world this is from a mouse". If it comes from your mouse, it cannot be the "automatic" one. See, simple! And you are welcome.